Division of binomial coefficients
Is there a nice way to simplify $$\frac{\binom{b}{n}}{\binom{a+b}{n}}?$$
I've got to the expression by starting with $$\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{b-i}{a+b-i}$$ and writing it as factorials - can I go further? I wondered if the repeated $n$ allows for simplification?
Edit: by "simplify" I suppose I'm asking can the fraction be represented by a single binomial coefficient, or at least perhaps some function of $n,a,b$ multiplied by a binomial coefficient? I want to do some further analysis on an expression involving this term so I wanted to know how I might be able to rewrite it.

Given two equivalent expressions, what criteria do you use to determine which expression is "simpler"?

Good point. I guess from an analytical point of view, the one using binomial coefficients is "simpler" than the product because the product has many terms in it so can be hard to manipulate. And then for the fraction to be simpler I suppose I'm asking can the fraction be written as one binomial coefficient, perhaps? Or some function of $n$ multiplied by one coefficient?

The product form should be the simplest you can get it, as this type of ratio between two binomial coefficients does not generally reduce to a single binomial coefficient unless under special cases for $a$ and $b$.  There isn't a standard binomial simplification that applies universally for arbitrary $a$, $b$ and $n$. Consider the special cases $a=0$ simplifying to $1$ or $b=0$ simplifying to $0$, but otherwise the product form is the simplest you can get it.

Thanks for confirming there isn't a standard binomial simplification
